# Jquery add leading zero to input type if number less than 7 digit

Tags: jquery, validation

I have create input type that only allow number with maximum 7 digits and what I want to create is must have a leading zero if is less than 7 digits.

so if I enter 123456 it must add 0 in front (0123456)
and if I enter 1234567 is will still 1234567

```
<input type="text" name="contact-number" class="field numeric" maxlength="7" required>

$(".numeric").keydown(function(event) {
if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
} else {
    if (event.keyCode < 95) {
    if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    }
    } else {
        if (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 ) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
    }
}
});

$(".numeric").keyup(function(e) {
var $this = $(this);
var val = $this.val();
if (val.length < 7)
{
    //e.preventDefault();
    $this.val(0);
}
});
```

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6vja/1/) link

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with something like this:

```
addLeadingZeros: function( value ) {
    return ('0000000' + value.toString()).slice( - value.length );
}
```

(written from head without testing, but you should ge the idea...)